# bash alias not able to create

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to create an alias in bash but am not able to do.

```
alias bundle-vendor= 'bundle install vendor --disable-shared-gems'
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the space after the equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the space after the = sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias bundle-vendor='bundle install vendor --disable-shared-gems'
```

It works for me.